# Storing images from [UIImage] array to Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have an UIImage array, images, which is declared as

```
var images = [UIImage]()
```

I currently have pictures stored in there, and when I output it using the println() function, I get

```
[<UIImage: 0x195dc810>, <UIImage: 0x195da3e0>, <UIImage: 0x1950ab50>]
```

I was wondering how I could upload these images to Parse as one row.

Here is my full code of what I have now(not working):

```
@IBAction func saveToParse(sender: AnyObject) {

    for var i = 0; i < images.count; i++
    {
        var objectForSave:PFObject = PFObject(className: "NewLog")
        //error on this line below:  [(UIImage)] does not have a member variable named 'objectAtIndex'
        let imageData:NSData = NSData(data: UIImagePNGRepresentation(images.objectAtIndex(i) as! UIImage))

        var imageFile:PFFile = PFFile(data: imageData)
        imageFile.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            if success{
                objectForSave.setObject(imageFile, forKey: "Image")

                objectForSave.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success:Bool, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                    if success{
                        //do smth
                    }else{
                        println(error)
                    }
                })

            }else{
                println(error)
            }

            }, progressBlock: { (progress:Int32) -> Void in

        })


    }     
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: try `for image in images` this way you will one image at a time, you can use this instead of the `images.objectAtIndex(i)`

Comment: Hey milo526, THANK YOU, worked wonderfully.  I am able to upload my picture to parse.

Comment: @JoshO'Connor Hey Josh, I have trying to do this feature (upload multiple images to parse) my self for over a week now but had absolute no luck! I only just came across your post! I have just tried to use the code above, and also changed the error for milo's answer. But it still doesn't seem to work!( it still gives me an error for image in images)  I'll open a question if you would be kind enough to help me figure this out! ;) Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the array and using the index, you can iterate over all the items in the array.

`for image in images`

This will get every single image in the array. Everything in the for loop will be executed once for every item in the array.

You would use `image` instead of `images.objectAtIndex(i) as! UIImage`

This will also make your code easier to read for others ;)